# iOS: Pickers broken on iOS 16, working on 15

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

I am working on creating a remote control app on iOS that involves pickers. On the iPhone SE, 3rd gen (iOS 15.6.1) I have been developing on, the pickers are coming out exactly as I intend. However, when I run the app on a simulator for a 3rd gen (16.1.1) iPhone SE, the pickers height is way off. Through testflight, I had a coworker download the app. He confirmed that, on his hardware, the pickers looked off. Here is what the picker is coming out like:

[image]

And here is how it looks on my iphone, how I intend it to look:

[image]

(My apologies for the different image sizes)

These pickers start as uninitialized class variables. When initializing the pickers, I want their height and width to be equal to the view they are seated in. When debugging this issue, I added two lines. One prints out the height argument I feed the constructor, and the other prints out the size of the picker after being constructed.

```
print("pickerRect height argument: " + String(Int(pickerFrame.frame.height))) // reading out 80
rolloffPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pickerFrame.frame.width, height: pickerFrame.frame.height))
print("picker height: " + String(Int(rolloffPicker.frame.height))) // reading out 162
```

Now here is whats baffling me... On the physical iPhone SE it prints out 80 on both lines. For whatever reason, in the sim, it prints out the argument as 80, and the initialized size as 162. I have also tried constructing the CGRect before passing it in, the CGRect readsout 80 after being constructed, but once fed into the picker the size shoots up to 162 again. I have not touched the rolloffPicker variable until this line, and don't have any autolayout going with the picker.

My Mac is on Ventura 13.0.1, XCode is on Version 14.1. The physical iPhone was on 15.6.1, and the sim is on 16.1.1. When I updated the physical iPhone to 16.1.2, the pickers broke! Clearly this issue is in relation to the new update? What changed, and how might I work around it?

Update: Can't believe I missed this, but I am getting this message in the console when constructing the picker:

`2022-12-09 19:35:14.434387-0700 Remote Control[645:22988] -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid size {107, 72} pinned to {107, 162}`

Update 2:

I tried to add constraints to the picker:

```
rolloffPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
rolloffPicker.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pickerFrame.frame.width).isActive = true
rolloffPicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pickerFrame.frame.height).isActive = true
```

Now I am getting warnings, pickers size is way off...

Comment: Ah, certainly! My apologies, a little rusty on my stackoverflow etiquette...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AHHHH I fixed it! I changed

```
rolloffPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

to

```
rolloffPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

while keeping the constraints. Why this broke between iOS 15 and 16 is an enigma to me, hopefully this can help someone else out in the future.

Comment: Not my downvotes but you should make further edits to the question and your answer to make it clear that the problem was trying to set the picker's frame and that the answer is to use constraints. The whole bit about getting the constraint warnings because you didn't set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is irrelevant. I'd remove all mention of that and focus on using constraints as being the answer.

Comment: I got rid of it for brevity. My thought was that it would make it more visible in the search engine if someone else was hunting for it. I saw a few other complaints of this on the Apple Developer Forums but nobody posted their solutions so I figured I would detail me working through it.